# is there a standard way to construct an array with two different types in 2 dimensions in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vba, casting

Is there any way to make a standard array with two different types in visual basic?

Example:

Array[string[]] [int[]]

---

| number1 | 1 |
| number2 | 2 |

### | number3 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can only be a single type. I would recommend a class

eg.

```
Public Class ExampleClass
    Dim strVariable As String
    Dim intVariable As Variable
End Class

'You can then declare the class as a list
Dim twoDataTypesInOne As New List(Of ExampleClass)

'Adding to the list would be
twoDataTypesInOne.Add(New ExampleClass() With {
                 .strVariable = "number3", _
                 .intVariable = 3 _
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create an array of objects and then you can assign everything to this array.

```
Dim myArray(2) As Object
    myArray(0) = "somestring"
    myArray(1) = 2
```